# editing wordpress nav button

Tags: wordpress, button, nav

I have started using wordpress yesterday and it's great. I really have so much to learn about PHP but the default php scripts are quite comprehensive for me but not everything. My objective is to create a custom nav button (MouseOver and MouseClick effect) but I can't seem to find where I should edit. I'm trying to change the default black and white Nav mouse hover effect of the twentyeleven theme. I tried looking at the style.css script but it does not show what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi here are some links which help you to start editing wordpress nav menu and style it

how it works :-
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

```
wp_nav_menu
```

function help to add menu in frontend you can find it in header.php

if you want to change class of div you need to go function.php

below are the link which will help you to achieve what you are looking for

http://kav.in/wordpress-dropdown-menu-wp-nav-menu-css/
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-style-wordpress-navigation-menus/

Answer (score 0):

20+ plugins for better navigation ->
http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/02/wordpress-menu-plugins.html